# can i do full text search including special characters?

Tags: c#, full-text-search, irony

I am using irony for full text search in c# application which works fine. Now my need is that i want to search a text including some special characters such as [, ], ;, ~, ', \, /, <, >, ,. When i do search with above special characters it shows error that "Syntax error, expected: - & ( ) Phrase StringLiteral Term | ~ < and not or (parser state: S5)".

Is there any way to do full text search including special characters?

This is my code where error occurs during  this call:_compiler.Parse(_compilerContext, source);

```
private void ConvertQuery()
{
    // Define Grammer
    SearchGrammar _grammar = new SearchGrammar();

    LanguageCompiler _compiler = new LanguageCompiler(_grammar);
    CompilerContext _compilerContext = new CompilerContext(_compiler);
    _compilerContext.Options |= CompilerOptions.MatchBraces | CompilerOptions.CollectTokens;

    if (_compiler.Grammar.FlagIsSet(LanguageFlags.SupportsInterpreter))
    {
        _compilerContext.Options |= CompilerOptions.AnalyzeCode;
    }

    // Parse each token to construct the SQL command.
    foreach (SearchToken token in tokens)
    {
        if (!token.IsDefined) continue;

        SourceFile source = new SourceFile(token.RawText, "Source", 8);
        AstNode root = _compiler.Parse(_compilerContext, source);

        string parseError = CheckParseErrors(_compilerContext);
        if (parseError != string.Empty)
        {
            token.ParseErrorMessage = parseError;
            token.IsParseError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            token.SQLText = SearchGrammar.ConvertQuery(root, SearchGrammar.TermType.Exact, token);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code that causes this error?

Comment: This sample doesn't really help, the grammar and the query would be more helpful ;)